# Trying to send a big file ,python socket

Tags: python, sockets, opencv

i trying to create a live stream from a webcam to other server . and my problem is 
the frame i'm geting is to big for the socket to handle
i'm geting this eror :

```
error: [Errno 10040] A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself
```

here is my code :

```
 import numpy as np
import cv2
import socket
import sys
import select
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
address = ('localhost', 6005)
client_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print (frame)
    client_socket.connect(('120.0.0.1', 6005))
    client_socket.sendto(frame, address)
```

i know c and i tought may be i can create a pointer to the frame and send it part by part 
so my question is how can i cast this method to python and if its possible

Comment: Try splitting it into multiple sends.

Comment: Note that the manual states: "Send data to the socket. The socket should not be connected to a remote socket, since the destination socket is specified by address."

Comment: I dont know how to do multi sends  .

Comment: udp packets are limited to 64k, you've *got* to split your image ( or give in, and switch to tcp, where this is handled 'under the hood' )

Comment: i know  whats udp limt and i have to use udp m problem is that i dont know how to split it , if it was c i'd just used a pointer and a while . but i dont know if its possible in py 2.7\

Answer (score 1):

From [Ans :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447684/error-trying-to-pass-large-image-over-socket-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

> Your image is too big to be sent in one UDP packet. You need to split
>   the image data into several packets that are sent individually.
>
> If you don't have a special reason to use UDP you could also use TCP
>   by specifying socket.SOCK_STREAM instead of socket.SOCK_DGRAM. There
>   you don't have to worry about packet sizes and ordering.

You can also look at [Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958957/best-way-to-send-string-data-using-python-udp-packets?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: i need to use UDP becuase its live web cam stream and i dont care if a packet is lost .